# Animate addition to android listview?

Tags: java, android, json, list, jquery-animate

In my application, I am fetching data from a JSON feed every 30 seconds and displaying it in a listview. The data and listview are working just fine, though, when it updates, the application just jolts and doesn't look right. Is there any way that I can animate this transition? As it updates, the data is just moving up an index, which is stored in a listview. This is my code to update my listview

```
list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
LiveAdapter adapter = new LiveAdapter(LiveStreamFragment.this.getActivity(), oslist, LiveStreamFragment.this, list);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: for updating adapter are you adding adapter again?

Comment: Yes, this code is called every thirty seconds

Comment: instead of adding entire adapter simply update(add) loaded items to the list in adapter and call notifyDatasetChanged(). if you want it as animation simply use smoothScrollTo() size before updating data

Answer (score 1):

Animate each added element in the getView() method of your Custom Adapter.

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;
       // Your code ..............
       if(flag == false) {
           Animation animation =  AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.slide_top_to_bottom);
           v.startAnimation(animation);
         }
        return v;
    }
```

LayoutTransition (introduced in Android 3.0) continues to provide functionality that makes some kinds of animations easier, specifically when adding, removing, hiding, and showing views. For example, either this snippet in a layout file:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"></ListView>
```

Animating changes with a ListView is a bit trickier than just setting the layout changes flag because of the view recycling that goes on with the Adapter. There is a series of DevBytes articles that Chet Haase has done explaining the issues and how to do this type of thing correctly here. Here is, I think, probably the most relevant one to your predicament.

[DevBytes: ListView Animations](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8MIfSxgsHIs)